# Provide functional-programming style solution for 2D Array - DS challenge

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, scala

> [Problem Statement:](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays)
>
> Given a **6×6** 2D Array, **arr**:
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```
>
> We define an hourglass in **A** to be a subset of values with indices
> falling in this pattern in **arr**'s graphical representation:
>
> ```
> a b c
>   d
> e f g
> ```
>
> There are **16** hourglasses in **arr**, and an hourglass sum is the
> sum of an hourglass' values. Calculate the hourglass sum for every
> hourglass in **arr**, then print the maximum hourglass sum.
>
> For example, given the 2D array:
>
> ```
> -9 -9 -9  1 1 1 
>  0 -9  0  4 3 2
> -9 -9 -9  1 2 3
>  0  0  8  6 6 0
>  0  0  0 -2 0 0
>  0  0  1  2 4 0
> ```
>
> We calculate the following **16** hourglass values:
>
> ```
> -63, -34, -9, 12, 
> -10, 0, 28, 23, 
> -27, -11, -2, 10, 
> 9, 17, 25, 18
> ```
>
> Our highest hourglass value is **28** from the hourglass:
>
> ```
> 0 4 3
>   1
> 8 6 6
> ```
>
> Note: If you have already solved the Java domain's Java 2D Array
> challenge, you may wish to skip this challenge.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the function hourglassSum in the editor below. It should
> return an integer, the maximum hourglass sum in the array.
>
> hourglassSum has the following parameter(s):
>
> - arr: an array of integers
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 2 4 4 0
> 0 0 0 2 0 0
> 0 0 1 2 4 0
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 19
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> **arr** contains the following hourglasses:
>
> [image: Preview]
>
> The hourglass with the maximum sum (19) is:
>
> ```
> 2 4 4
>   2
> 1 2 4
> ```

**Following is my imperative style Solution:**

```
def hourglassSum(arr: Array[Array[Int]]): Int = {
  def sum(rowNumber: Int, columnNumber: Int): Int = {
    var oneHourglassSum = 0
    for {
      i <- 0 to 2
      j <- 0 to 2
    } yield {
      val cumulativeSum = if (i == 1 && (j == 0 || j == 2)) 0
      else arr(i + rowNumber)(j + columnNumber)
      oneHourglassSum += cumulativeSum
    }
    oneHourglassSum
  }

  def max(x: Int, y: Int): Int = if (x > y) x else y

  var hourglassMaxSum = 0
  for {
    rowOffset <- 0 to 3
    columnOffset <- 0 to 3
  } yield {
    hourglassMaxSum = max(sum(rowOffset, columnOffset), hourglassMaxSum)
  }
  hourglassMaxSum
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to write a `max()` method. The Standard Library provides for that.

A `for` comprehension, with a `yield` clause, produces a result. So instead of using a mutable `var` to capture and collect the results of the `yield` you should capture them directly.

```
val res = for {...} yield {...}
```

Or, if you want to process the results more directly, i.e. without the intermediate variable, you can use the somewhat awkward parentheses construct.

```
def hourglassSum(arr: Array[Array[Int]]): Int = {
  (for {
    x <- 0 to 3
    y <- 0 to 3
  } yield {
    arr(y)(x)   + arr(y)(x+1)   + arr(y)(x+2) +
                  arr(y+1)(x+1) +
    arr(y+2)(x) + arr(y+2)(x+1) + arr(y+2)(x+2)
  }).max
}
```